# How do i use itext7.pdfhtml in AGPL mode?

Tags: itext, itext7

I'm trying to use itext7.pdfhtml to convert a html string to a pdf document in a C# .Net project.
When I run this code:

```
iText.Html2pdf.HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(htmlString, pdfStream)
```

I get the following exception: *iText.License.LicenseKeyException: License file for product not loaded*.

I don't want to load a trial license or a commercial license. I want to run itext7 in AGPL mode. How do I do that?

I'm using:

- itext7 v7.0.3
- itext7.licensekey v2.0.4
- itext7.pdfhtml v1.0.0.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>You can't. pdfHTML is currently (version 1.0.0) only available as a Commercial product. You can use a free 30 day trial, but you cannot use it in AGPL mode.</s>

You can however use iText 7 Core, without pdfHTML, in AGPL mode.

Please note that this answer is only valid for pdfHTML version 1.0.0, which is the only version released so far. At this moment there is no publicly available information if or when there will be an AGPL version of pdfHTML.

**UPDATE**

pdfHTML 1.0.1, scheduled for release end of July 2017, will also not be available in an AGPL version.

**UPDATE**

We are currently in the last stages of making pdfHTML ready for Open Source. It should appear on GitHub and Maven Central somewhere next week, and not long after on NuGet for the .NET port.

**UPDATE**

pdfHTML 2.0.1, compatible with iText 7.1.1 and Licensekey 3.0.1, is most definitely available as dual license AGPL/Commercial.

Comment: It is free to use for commercial projects?

Comment: Please contact iText Software directly. I no longer work there, and I am unable to answer your question.